# s = null, can't retrieve data from firebase, retrieveing data as null

Tags: android, database, firebase, null, snapshot

I've got an issue with firebase as it seems to result will null results from the database. In the debug app, I can see s = null with the line below:

```
String list_project = dataSnapshot.child("users").child("Project Name").getValue(String.class);
```

Please see the code below:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    public DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private ListView mProjectList;
    ArrayList<String> list_project=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mProjectList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ProjectList);
        adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list_project);
        mProjectList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();
        // final DatabaseReference mRef = mDatabase.getRef();
         final DatabaseReference mRef = mDatabase.child("users");

        mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

           String list_project = dataSnapshot.child("users").child("Project Name").getValue(String.class);


                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

Comment: What is `s` supposed to be?

Comment: The `s` argument to `onChildAdded` is `previousKey` (see the [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener.html#onChildAdded(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot, java.lang.String))). Not sure why the auto-complete gives it such a terrible name. :-/